# How to pass data from Vue component to Laravel route or controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using Laravel with a Vue component called vue-good-table. I just want to pass an array from my component to one of my Laravel routes and consequently to the respective controller. 
I tried with axios but in this case it doesn't work, because the controller that receives the data must return straight away a Laravel view (but using axios the view is returned to the Vue component method as a response).

Maybe I can try to use a button that calls the route but I'm having trouble passing the array I need to pass. The route I specified must use the GET method.

**MyTable.vue**

```
<a :href="/pdf-download-selected/">
   <button>Download PDF</button>
</a>
```

I really don't understand if my approach to Laravel with Vue is completely wrong or what..I mean I know how to pass data from Laravel to Vue, but not the opposite.
What do you recommend I do?

Thanks!

Comment: As you mentioned that while suing axios, the controller is returning a view. Why not just create another controller method that passes json?

Comment: Hi Digvijay, thanks but I don't think this could solve my problems.